# How do you display outputs with multiple lines of different functions to print next to each other?

Tags: python

Basically, my assignment is to simulate rolling dice and printing them out side by side depending on what was rolled. The dice have take up 5 lines each so I need a way to print out all 5 lines next to another die result of all 5 lines.

The program that I have been trying attempted to convert the functions into regular strings but it wasn't working and I also tried putting ,end = '' in the functions themselves and simply put them right under each other but I had no luck there either. I only posted in the case of if the first die is a 1.

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    return random.choice(['1','2','3','4','5','6'])

def display_die1():
    print("+-------+")
    print("|       |")
    print("|   *   |")
    print("|       |")
    print("+-------+")

def display_die2():
    print("+-------+")
    print("| *     |")
    print("|       |")
    print("|     * |")
    print("+-------+")

def display_die3():
    print("+-------+")
    print("| *     |")
    print("|   *   |")
    print("|     * |")
    print("+-------+")

def display_die4():
    print("+-------+")
    print("| *   * |")
    print("|       |")
    print("| *   * |")
    print("+-------+")

def display_die5():
    print("+-------+")
    print("| *   * |")
    print("|   *   |")
    print("| *   * |")
    print("+-------+")

def display_die6():
    print("+-------+")
    print("| * * * |")
    print("|       |")
    print("| * * * |")
    print("+-------+")

def main():
    pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6 = display_die1(), display_die2(), display_die3(), display_die4(), display_die5(), display_die6()
    print(f"Craps: A Popular Dice Game")
    prompt = input(f"Press <Enter> to roll the dice.")
    if prompt == (""):
        x = roll_dice()
        y = roll_dice()
        add = int(x) + int(y)
        if x == '1':
            if y == '1':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic1)
            if y == '2':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic2)
            if y == '3':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic3)
            if y == '4':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic4)
            if y == '5':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic5)
            if y == '6':
                print(pic1, end = '')
                print(pic6)
        stopper = int(x) + int(y)
        if add == (7 or 11):
            print(f"You rolled a {add} on your first roll.")
            print(f"You win!")
        elif add == (2 or 3 or 12):
            print(f"You rolled a {add} on your first roll.")
            print(f"You lose!")
        else:
            print(f"You rolled a {add} on your first roll.")
            print(f"\nThat's your point. Roll it again before you roll a 7 and lose!")
            while add != (7 or stopper):
                proceed = input(f"\nPress <Enter> to roll the dice.")
                if proceed == (""):                
                    x = roll_dice()
                    y = roll_dice()
                    add = int(x) + int(y)
                    if (add == 7):
                        print(f"You rolled a 7.")
                        print(f"You lose!")
                        break
                    elif (add == stopper):
                        print(f"You rolled a {stopper}.")
                        print(f"You win!")
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"You rolled a {add}")

main()
```

I would expect the output to be two dice displaying next to each other with three spaces in between but the actual output is a very jumbled, twisted version of the two dice on one line.

Comment: `display_die1()` prints a dice and returns `None`, so `pic1` is `None`, and not some string representing a dice as it seems that you expect. You should define your dices as strings, or probably better as lists of lines if you want to be able to print them side by side.

Comment: `print("⚀ ⚁ ⚂ ⚃ ⚄ ⚅")`......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big problem is in this line:

```
pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6 = display_die1(), display_die2(), display_die3(), display_die4(), display_die5(), display_die6()
```

Let's simplify it to a single assignment and find the mistake:

```
pic1 = display_die()
```

will result in the following:

In the console:

```
+-------+
| * * * |
|       |
| * * * |
+-------+
```

And `pic1 == None`.

Another problem is, that you can only print line by line and not jump back. So you need a mechanism, to print in one line two "lines" for each dice.

A solution would be to store every line of a dice in a list element:

```
def get_dice_1():
    lines = [
    "+-------+",
    "| * * * |",
    "|       |",
    "| * * * |",
    "+-------+"  
    ]
```

To print two dice:

```
def print_dices(list_dice_1, list_dice_2):
    for i range(len(list_dice_1)):
        line = list_dice_1[i] + "   " + list_dice_2[i]
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep dice as lists of rows

```
die3 = [
    "+-------+",
    "| *     |",
    "|   *   |",
    "|     * |",
    "+-------+",
]    


die4 = [
    "+-------+",
    "| *   * |",
    "|       |",
    "| *   * |",
    "+-------+",
]
```

and then you can use `zip()` to create pairs `[first row of die3, first row of die4]`, `[second row of die3, second row of die4]`, etc. And then you can concatenate pair using `"".join()` and display it

```
for rows in zip(die3, die4):
    #print(rows)
    print(''.join(rows))

+-------++-------+
| *     || *   * |
|   *   ||       |
|     * || *   * |
+-------++-------+
```

you can do the same with more dice

```
for rows in zip(die3, die4, die4, die3):
    print(''.join(rows))

+-------++-------++-------++-------+
| *     || *   * || *   * || *     |
|   *   ||       ||       ||   *   |
|     * || *   * || *   * ||     * |
+-------++-------++-------++-------+
```

If you need space between dice then use space in `" ".join(rows)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Should have realized to put them in lists I guess...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to store the dice in a list and then you can print each row of the dice with string formatting methods. An example of this would be:

```
import random

dice_list = [
[
    "+-------+",
    "|       |",
    "|   *   |",
    "|       |",
    "+-------+"],
    [
    "+-------+",
    "| *     |",
    "|       |",
    "|     * |",
    "+-------+"],
    [
    "+-------+",
    "| *     |",
    "|   *   |",
    "|     * |",
    "+-------+"],
    [
    "+-------+",
    "| *   * |",
    "|       |",
    "| *   * |",
    "+-------+"],
    [
    "+-------+",
    "| *   * |",
    "|   *   |",
    "| *   * |",
    "+-------+"],
    [
    "+-------+",
    "| * * * |",
    "|       |",
    "| * * * |",
    "+-------+"]
]

roll1 = random.randint(0, 5)
roll2 = random.randint(0, 5)

for i in range(5): # number of rows of strings per dice
    print("{}   {}".format(dice_list[roll1][i], dice_list[roll2][i]))
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
+-------+   +-------+
| * * * |   | * * * |
|       |   |       |
| * * * |   | * * * |
+-------+   +-------+
```

Something to note though is the range of dice rolls with this method is 0-5 so if you wanted to say, `print('You rolled a 2 and a 5')` you would have to add 1 to both `roll1` and `roll2` so the numbers will match up!

Comment: I really like this suggestion as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I know that there is already an answer selected to this post but here is an alternate solution using the yield keyword which can be used in sequences. I had this thought before but didn't have enough time to make the code for it. If anything, it is nice to see another way to accomplish the same thing. :)

```
def display_die1():
    yield ("+-------+")
    yield ("|       |")
    yield ("|   *   |")
    yield ("|       |")
    yield ("+-------+")


def display_die2():
    yield ("+-------+")
    yield ("| *     |")
    yield ("|       |")
    yield ("|     * |")
    yield ("+-------+")

dice1 = display_die1()
dice2 = display_die2()

for line in range(0,5):
    print(f"{next(dice1)}    {next(dice2)}")
```

Here is the output:

```
+-------+    +-------+
|       |    | *     |
|   *   |    |       |
|       |    |     * |
+-------+    +-------+
```

I hope it helps!

################ My Older answer

Using docstrings instead of printing each individual line will give you a more consistent output.

```
def display_die1():
    dice = '''
+-------+
|       |
|   *   |
|       |
+-------+
    '''
    return dice

def display_die2():
    dice = '''
+-------+
| *     |
|       |
|     * |
+-------+
    '''
    return dice

print(f"{str(display_die1())}   {str(display_die2())}")
```

Not side by side but one on top of the other in this case.

Here is the output

```
python ./testing/dice_test.py

+-------+
|       |
|   *   |
|       |
+-------+

+-------+
| *     |
|       |
|     * |
+-------+
```

Comment: I think the OP wants "I would expect the output to be two dice displaying next to each other with three spaces in between", but maybe they would be OK with this solution